# ‘One egg was given to three people’

Tags: meaning

Can ‘one egg was given to three people’ mean ‘one egg each was given to three people’? Or does it only mean the one egg was shared by three people?

Comment: @Hot Licks You mean ‘one egg was give to three people’ means there were three eggs given?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before, but it's very hard to search for this kind of question.

Comment: @Stuart F What about ‘there’s one egg to three people’? Can it mean technically ‘there’s one egg each to three people’?

Comment: @Stuart F Please help me

Comment: @user029384 - I meant what I said -- it's intentionally ambiguous.

Comment: @Hot Licks Thank you!

Comment: @user029384 - For some reason my original comment was deleted.